# mime type not executable

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a problem with joining the file rocketchat-livechat.min.js.

Error is:

Refused to execute script from '...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        (function(w, d, s, u) {
            w.RocketChat = function(c) { 
                w.RocketChat._.push(c) 
            }; 
            w.RocketChat._ = []; 
            w.RocketChat.url = u;
            var h = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], 
                j = d.createElement(s);
            j.async = true; j.src = 'rocketchat-livechatmin.js';
            h.parentNode.insertBefore(j, h);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'xxx');
    </script>       
</body>
```

The file is in the same directory as the html document. Has anyone had a similar problem? What can be done to solve it? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you show your directory structure?

Comment: Most probably your web server is sending the `rocketchat-livechatmin.js` file with a wrong MIME type. I.e. check the web server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are receiving 'text/html' as MIME type instead of 'application/javascript'

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types